# ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator Triggers CompareValidator

Tags: asp.net

Basically, I've got code that looks like this:

```
<div>

  <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" class="inline-block" runat="server" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTxtBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ErrorMessage="Enter an integer or decimal greater than 0." Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$)|(^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$)" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldTxtBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ErrorMessage="Requires a number." Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="" />
  <asp:CompareValidator id="cmprTxtBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ControlToCompare="txtBox2" Type="Double" Display="Dynamic" Operator="LessThanEqual" Text="Error: txtBox1 is greater than txtBox2." />

</div>

<br />

<div>

  <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTxtBox2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox2" ErrorMessage="Enter an integer or decimal greater than 0." Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$)|(^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$)" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldTxtBox2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox2" ErrorMessage="Requires a number." Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="" />

</div>
```

I've got two text boxes that use regular expression validators in order to force the user to only enter integers or decimals.  I also want the input in txtBox2 to be larger than txtBox1, so I use a compare validator on txtBox1 in order to check for when the number in txtBox1 is larger than txtBox2.

The issue that I'm running into is that my CompareValidator always triggers when the RegularExpressionValidator triggers. The CompareValidator is perfectly content when there are normal numbers in txtBox1 and nothing in txtBox2. But it fails whenever the RegularExpressionValidator fails, regardless of what's in txtBox2.

Of course, the system functions correctly, because either way the user won't be able to enter any values when the validators are returning invalid. But I don't want the user to see unnecessary error messages.

If there isn't any solution I think I could implement a custom validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround.

For the text box with the compare validator I added an 'onchange' call to a javascript method. In that method, it checks whether or not the regular expression has failed. If it has, it sets the compare validator to true and then updates the display.

The implementation in javascript looks like this:

```
function txtBoxChanged() {

    var txtBox1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtBox1.ClientID%>').value;

    var rgx = new RegExp(/^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$|^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$/)

    if (!(rgx.test(txtBox1))) {

      document.getElementById('<%=cmprTxtBox1.ClientID%>').isvalid = true;
      ValidatorUpdateDisplay(document.getElementById('<%=cmprTxtBox1.ClientID%>'));

    }

}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div>

  <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" class="inline-block" runat="server" onchange="txtBoxChanged()" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTxtBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ErrorMessage="Enter an integer or decimal greater than 0." Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$)|(^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$)" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldTxtBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ErrorMessage="Requires a number." Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="" />
  <asp:CompareValidator id="cmprTxtBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ControlToCompare="txtBox2" Type="Double" Display="Dynamic" Operator="LessThanEqual" Text="Error: txtBox1 is greater than txtBox2." />

</div>

<div>

  <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server" onchange="txtBoxChanged()" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExTxtBox2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox2" ErrorMessage="Enter an integer or decimal greater than 0." Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="(^0*[1-9]+\d*(\.\d+)?$)|(^0*\.0*[1-9]+\d*$)" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFldTxtBox2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox2" ErrorMessage="Requires a number." Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="" />

</div>
```

I had to make it so both text boxes were calling this method. Otherwise even when the regular expression failed on txtBox2 the compare validator would show up. Which makes sense because it is looking at both text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check By Using **Validation Group** Property.....
For and Validation Control and put Same Validation Group To Submit Button so it will Validate On Button Click.....
I hope It Will Helps You.....